# Storing a user password temporarily

Tags: security, passwords, password-encryption

I have a use case where a user registers for my service, and then confirms their registration via email. The problem I have is that I have to wait until the email is confirmed in order to create the account (this is an external requirement that I cannot change), so I have to store the password somewhere so that it's retrievable in plain text.

What's the best way of doing this? The solution that comes to mind is to encrypt it and store it in redis until the user authenticates, then create the account and remove the redis entry.

Is that the best/most secure way of doing this?

Comment: Why can't you hash + salt the password and store that value? If you have to provide the 3rd party with a password, do so when the user enters it but don't store it as plain text. Once the user confirms the account with the email, you can create their account using the hashed + salted value of the password. Then on future authentication attempts you just compare the value they enter in for the password with the hashed + salted value in your database.

Comment: @bsimic: The point is I'm trying not to store their password at all, ever in any of my databases. Also, the user can then access the external system without going through me, so their password has to work on the other system too.

Comment: Does this third party by any chance an OAuth service provider? If so you could do that. Another option is to use something like Open ID (http://openid.net/) where you don't have to do your own authentication at all. You can see how OpenID works here http://www.windley.com/archives/2006/04/how_does_openid.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Change the process: don't ask for the password upfront, do the address verification first.

Registration form takes only the e-mail address, and sends a token to the e-mail address in a link. Typically something like:

```
http://.../verify?email=bob@example.com&expires=nnn&sig=xxx
```

where nnn is a timestamp after which the link becomes useless and xxx is `HMAC(serversecret, email+timestamp)` so you can authenticate.

Following the link gets them a signup page with a password field and any other details.

(Bonus: use the same process for forgotten password journey if you have one, so following the link either gets you a signup page or a recover-account page.)

Comment: The serversecret should be quiet strong, otherwise such url's can be forged and can easily become the weakest link in your password handling.

Comment: I thought about this but I don't think requiring the user to put in a password after verification is an acceptable option.